# Running perl script in lambda function with python3.6 runtime

Tags: python, perl, aws-lambda

I am trying to run an [exiftool](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) for reading image meta data within a python script, as part of a lambda function on AWS.

On an ec2 instance running amazon linux, [which is what the python3.6 runtime uses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html), I can download the tool, extract it, then run it easily. However, trying to do this from my python script in the lambda function does not work.

My lambda function is as follows:

```
import imageio
import subprocess
import utils
import os
import stat
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

# get exif tool
s3_client.download_file(
    'zipped.code',
    'Image-ExifTool-11.53.tar.gz', 
    '/tmp/Image-ExifTool-11.53.tar.gz')
p = subprocess.run('tar -zxvf Image-ExifTool-11.53.tar.gz', cwd='/tmp', shell=True)

def get_meta_data(im):
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        '/tmp/Image-ExifTool-11.53/exiftool -',
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=True)
    out, err = p.communicate(input=imageio.imwrite('<bytes>', im, format='jpg'))
    print(out) # b''
    print(err) # b'/bin/sh: /tmp/Image-ExifTool-11.53/exiftool: /usr/bin/perl: bad interpreter: No such file or directory\n'


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    src_key = event['src_key']
    image = utils.download_image_to_memory(src_key)
    print(get_meta_data(image))
```

I have ran this code locally and it works. If I print the contents of `/usr/bin` within the lambda function by `print(os.listdit('/usr/bin'))` there is no `perl` executable in there. However in the `/usr/bin` directory on an ec2 instance with amazon linux the `perl` executable is there.

I suspect the problem is my lack of perl (the tool is written in perl), but why is there no perl interpretter given that lambdas are supposed to run with the amazon linux image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding to your Referenced Layers one of the ARNs listed in https://p3rl.org/AWS::Lambda (there are instructions there).

I haven't done this myself, but from everything I see it should work.

Comment: I'm sorry I can only upvote you once. Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!

Comment: Just in case anybody else ends up here, the only amendment I had to make aside from @ysth suggestion was to change the shebang to point to `/opt/bin/perl` as this is where the runtime keeps the interpreter.